# What's the different between the core versions in SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I wrote a number of SSJS before, but a question that just can't sort it out: the core version.

From the [official document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_syntaxGuide.htm): it said:

> Given that the Core library has 1, 1.1, 1.2 and 2.0 versions, the load gets version 1.2 of the library.

However, it didn't explain the difference between each core version. So I'd like to know this. And, which version should I use now? EMCAScript 6 is very cool but I know SSJS does NOT support it well. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think those numbers mean anything, they are to show how you would load a specific versions if those versions existed.

> The Core library currently stands at version 1.1.1 and supports ECMAscript 3.0. This version represents the current, original version of the server-side JavaScript library and contains no revisions.
>
> The numbers used in this section represent examples only. Load the library using the syntax below:

The examples do make it confusing though.

Comment: I don't want this answer is the truth but it's very likely. Then it's meaningless to set it to other values.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for ECMAscript 2015. :( ECMAscript 3 is from 1999.